# Filtering data with sed

Tags: sed

I need a help. 
I have a file like

```
sometext line 1
sometext line 2
SU0000 
ID
ID
ID
sometext line 3
sometext line 4
sometext line 5
sometext line 6
SU0000 
ID
ID
ID
sometext line 7
sometext line 8
```

I want to filter text such that the output is

```
sometext line 2
SU0000 
ID
ID
ID
sometext line 6
SU0000 
ID
ID
ID
```

In other words, I want to get the line before the pattern and all the lines after it starting with ID.

I want to do this in sed. Can someone help please.

Comment: What is your `pattern` here? You say that you need line before the pattern followed by all lines starting with `ID`, but your sample out has `sometext line 6` Can u make it clear?

Comment: Hi Clement Thanks for replying. The pattern is 'SU'. I am trying to extract one line above this pattern and all the following lines that start with ID. Then repeat this process for a large file containing such data. Did you understand it ?.

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. It is not what *sed* was designed to do.

You can do it instead with *grep*, if the number of occurrences of *ID* is fixed. If instead it is variable, you will need something more powerful, like a bash or perl script.

If the number of occurrences of ID is fixed (say, 3), then the following command

```
  grep -B 1 -A 3 SU0000 filename.txt
```

will do what you require.

EDIT:

if the number of occurrences of SU0000 is not fixed, the following script will do the trick for you, where the file to be parsed is called "data". Change it as it best suits you.

```
  #!/bin/bash

  I_INSIDE=0
  PREVIOUS_LINE=""

  while read line; do
    echo $line | grep -e SU0000 2>&1 1>/dev/null
    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
            echo $PREVIOUS_LINE
            echo $line
            I_INSIDE=1
            PREVIOUS_LINE=$line
            continue
    fi
    echo $line | grep -e ID 2>&1 1>/dev/null
    if [ $? == 0 -a $I_INSIDE == 1 ]; then
            echo $line
    else
            I_INSIDE=0
    fi
    PREVIOUS_LINE=$line

  done < data
```

It is a very elementary script, to allow you to follow every instruction. it could have been condensed considerably.

Comment: Thank you Marius. I am aware of the grep command you mentioned. Unfortunately the occurrences of 'ID' are not fixed. Can you show me the bash/perl scripts which can do this.

Comment: Thank you so much Marius. I will check this and will let you know.